# Showing bottomNavigationBar only when futurebuilder is built

Tags: flutter

I have a bottom nav bar which contains a button. I want to display the button only when in the futurebuilder there is data and connection is done.

So far, I have introduced a boolean variable called loadButton which is initially set to false. Then Inside my future builder, in the if condition of connectionSate = done, I set loadButton to true. And then I control the visibility of the bottomNavBar using this boolean variable.

So far, the button is never visible. I only see a continuous loading spinner. How do I change the boolean value?

Here's the code:

```
FutureBuilder( 
      future: _someFuture, 
      builder: (ctx,dataSnapshot){ 
      if(dataSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) 
        loadButton = true; 
    }), 
    bottomNavigationBar: loadButton?MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () => {},
              child: Text(_register ? 'REGISTER' : 'LOGIN'),
            ):Center(child:Loading())
```

Comment: `loadButton = true` means that you are updating the value, but in your case you need to refresh the UI too, you should update the value within `setState `, makes sense ?

Comment: Cannot use setState inside the build function. That's another issue am facing.

Comment: A better way is to make you button a `StatefulWidget` and render it if you have data, or why you don't use the `FutureBuilder` as a child of `bottomNavigationBar` ?

Comment: How do I make a button a stateful widget? That sounds like it might work but will appreciate if you can provide an example.

Comment: Normal way to declare any StatefullWidget, your `App` an example, and return the `FutureBuilder` with Your button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn it around, transform `bottomNavigationBar` to be the `FutureBuilder`:

```
bottomNavigationBar: FutureBuilder(
    future: _someFuture,
    builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return Center(child: Loading());
      } else {
          return MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () => {},
              child: Text(_register ? 'REGISTER' : 'LOGIN'));
      }
    }),
```